# Show that an entirely real, non-negative covariance matrix has a precision matrix with non-positive off-diagonal elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, covariance

I was told in lecture that if a precision matrix $J$ has non-positive off-diagonal elements i.e. $\forall i\neq j,  J_{ij} \leq 0 $, then the corresponding covariance matrix $J^{-1}$ has all non-negative off diagonal elements i.e $\forall i \neq j, (J^{-1})_{ij} \geq 0$. Is the converse true? How can I show this?

Comment: Because $J$ is symmetric and PD and has nonpositive off-diagonal elements, it's an M-matrix.  The inverse of an M matrix has elements that are nonnegative, but I,m not sure that all PD matrices with nonnegative elements are necessarily M-matrices.  I'd start by looking in Horn and Johnson's Topics in Matrix Analysis for relevant results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.  A counter example is:

$A=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
4 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 4 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$

with

$A^{-1}=\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
0.5833 & 0.5000 & -0.6667 \\
0.5000 & 1.0000 & -1.0000 \\
-0.6667 & -1.0000 & 1.3333 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$.

This counterexample can be found in

Nabben, Reinhard, and Richard S. Varga. "A linear algebra proof that the inverse of a strictly ultrametric matrix is a strictly diagonally dominant Stieltjes matrix." SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications 15.1 (1994): 107-113.  [http://www.math.kent.edu/~varga/pub/paper_205.pdf](http://www.math.kent.edu/%7Evarga/pub/paper_205.pdf)

Comment: Hi Brian, I think this shows that a nonpositive precision yields a nonnegative covariance, but I asked for the converse i.e. does a nonnegative covariance yield a nonpositive precision?

Comment: The paper says that these conditions are "equivalent" which generally means "if and only if."

Comment: Hmmm. I dug into this more and I think the proper term for a nonpositive off-diagonal precision is a Stieltjes matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_matrix) and Wikipedia states that while every square Stieltjes matrix is invertible to a non-negative symmetric matrix (i.e. the covariance), but that the converse is not true in general for $n>2$

Comment: I've updated the answer with a counterexample and a reference.

Comment: Delightful. Thank you for investigating for me!